# Foreach Loop wont loop after exploded variable.. help required

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am having trouble showing a row from a database which has a list of skills as an array which is delimited by a commas. Fully annotated code with explanation below is what i've done sor far. All help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
// DB Connection here

    // Execute Query 
    $sql        =   "SELECT id, skills FROM p_info";
    $result     =   mysql_query($sql);
    $row        =   mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // Delimit array by comma
    $myArray = explode(',', $row['skills']);

    // Store as array
    $myArr   = array($myArray);

    /** 
    Assume the value of is skills row in the database is: type 1, type 2,  type 3, type 4 
    i would like to show these values each on a seperate <li> element hence using a loop. 

    <li> type 1</li>
    <li> type 2</li>
    <li> type 3</li>
    <li> type 4</li>

    My guess would be to use foreach loop..but im a little confused how to  go about this. Here whats i think logically:

    **/
    ?>
        <ul>
        <?
            foreach ( $myArr as $skills ) { 
        ?>
            <li><?=$myArr;?></li>

        <? 
            } // End loop 
        ?>
        </ul>

    <!-- Can someone tell me what im doing wrong? im fairly new to PHP but im a quick learner. :) -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$myArr   = array($myArray);` and do `foreach ( $myArray as $skills ) {` instead.
You are putting your array within a new array, so when you try to loop through it you end up with the original array.

Also change `<?=$myArr;?>` to `<?=$skills;?>`, you are looping through `$myArray` and storing every part in `$skills` temporarily, `$myArray` doesn't change so it's useless trying to `echo` it.

Comment: Thank you. I see my error, abit clumsy not to notice it. Worked. :)

Comment: On an other note; you might want to refrain from using the short-form `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`, as the first alternative isn't 100% reliable (might or might not be supported on server `x`). If you know for certain that the `short_tags`-directive will be enabled on each and every server you'll be using, no problem - if not, you better start using the full-scaled syntax. `'<?php echo' > ('<?=' +  broken code)` any day of the week. :D

Answer (score 0):

`explode` already returns an array. Wrapping that result in an array will give you something like this:

```
array(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
```

When looping over the outer array, of course you won't get the results of the inner array. Just get rid of `$myArr = array($myArray)` and use `$myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

- The "store as array" line is not needed. `$myArray` is already an array.
- Write `<li><?php echo $skills; ?>` instead of `$myArr`. That's the array.
- Don't use short open tags (`<?`) use `<?php` instead

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked a charm. Can i ask the reason for using full tags rather than short? (just for reference)

Comment: @Kay Shah: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808365/difference-between-php-and/1808372

Answer (score 0):

No need to do `$myArr   = array($myArray);` as `explode()` already returns an array.

You can always do a `var_dump($myArray)` on your array or any other variable to see what's in there.

Comment: All your help is much appreciated. Very fast, this is the firt time i used web help, usually i sit n grind it til i figure it out.. wasn't expecting a reply, not till tomorrow at least. :)