# Dropdown list from mysql is not visible and accepts space

Tags: php

I have table named `coursemaster` which has 3 columns: `id`, `course_code` and `course_name`. I would like to get the `course_code` value in dropdown list from mysql but it is not visible in the dropdown list and I want to select the value.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="slseatapp";
$tbl_name="coursemaster";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === false) { echo "An error occurred."; }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="usrname" id="usrname">
      <option>Select employ</option>
      <?php
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>
      <option value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><? echo $rows['course_code']; ?></option>
      <?php
        }
        mysql_close();
      ?>
    </select>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: are you sure your query is returning the correct results ? your php/html code for dropdown looks right. Try changing this: <? echo $rows['id']; ?> to this maybe: <?php echo $rows['id']; ?>

Comment: it is working but how to get a selected value.Thanks

Comment: what happens when you replace <? with <?php ?

Comment: <option value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" <?php if($row['course_code'] == 'something'){ echo "selected"; }?>><? echo $rows['course_code']; ?></option>

Comment: when i select a value in dropdown list it is not printing selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your code working using safe open-close tag(`<?php ?>`), may be your php.ini does not provide short open-close tag (`<? ?>`), You can also edit to support short open-close tag

```
<html>
<?php $rows['id']=1;$rows['course_code']='1_1';?>
  <select><option value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['course_code'];?> </option></select>
</html>
```

also know the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808365/difference-between-php-and)
there is no error in your code other than short tag :)