# What is the difference between <? and <?php

Tags: php

Why people can use both `<?` and `<?php`? Why are they different ? What are the use cases for both (if there is any) ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808365/difference-between-php-and

Comment: As a PHP novice, this was the first question that pointed me to "short tags". Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?` is short tag for `<?php`. You can use both of them as per you feel comfortable to use one of them.
However I will recommend you to stick to `<?php` as it is the industry standard.

**Now comes the question of how to enable them:**

You first need to specify it in your PHP.ini (settings) that whether you want to use it or not.

Modify `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini file and then restart your apache server.

If you are using a shared hosting over the internet, you cannnot edit php.ini file as they do not give access to it. But you can still solve the problem using `.htaccess`. Just add this code to your .htaccess file:
`php_value short_open_tag 1`.

---

- Source: [www.PHPonwebsites.com](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2013/11/how-to-enable-short-tag-in-wamp-using.html)

Answer (score 5):

`<?` is a [short tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). They are designed to save a few keystrokes, but are more trouble than they are worth (e.g. interfering with the XML declaration) and are turned off by default in recent versions of PHP. Don't use them.

`<?php` is the normal way to switch from "dump code to STDOUT" to "execute code" mode.