# Are there different between <?php and <? in PHP?

Tags: php

Sometimes when I use **'php codes'** working with `<?php` and sometimes working with `<?` as this code

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
           echo 'There is a url!';
        }
?>
```

Doesn't work to remove **php** after and use `<?`, but sometimes working in another projects!

I want to know there are different between `<?php` and `<?` ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808365/difference-between-php-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do the same thing. However, you should use `<?php` unless you're ***completely*** sure that you will have full control over the configuration of your server. I say this because short tags (`<?`) can be disabled on certain hosts and using short tags can make your code less portable.

Comment: As mention above correctly by @suchit and Wayne,

Still if You want to use short Tags, 



Set

short_open_tag=On

in php.ini

And restart your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a safe open and close tag variation, the second is the so called short-open tag. The second one is not always available, use the first option if it's possible. You could check the availability of short open tags in php.ini, at the short_open_tag.

Comment: -1. You ditto copied this answer without quoting the source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1808372/87015

Comment: Another thing is, you can use on `short_open_tag`: `<?=` which is short for `<?php echo`. Wow, you copied the answer?!?